# Location elements in TabHost (android)

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

Trying to make clear `TabWidget` finally happened, but all the elements that are in this layout is lowered to the end, until the end of the screen that are behind `TabWidget`, what would have been clearer to me now that the going to add a picture:

[image]

For TabWidget are members. I tried the margin and padding to rectify the situation, but to no avail

code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
           >

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                />

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:background="#D92a5094"
                android:fadingEdge="none"
                android:showDividers="none" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </TabHost>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is happening because obviously the inner `RelativeLayout` was meant to be `LinearLayout`.

I would suggest to keep the `RelativeLayout` and remove its `orientation` attribute (it is useless in `RelativeLayout`). That applies to the `weights` as well. Your content should be placed above the tabs like this

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tabs" />
```